png file not creating in visual studio code for mingrammer diagram
I am running a sample mingrammer diagram python code provided here in Microsoft Visual Studio Code. It will create a .png file as output but I am getting some file with some text content. Like below:
I am using this python code:
# diagram.py
from diagrams import Diagram
from diagrams.aws.compute import EC2
from diagrams.aws.database import RDS
from diagrams.aws.network import ELB

with Diagram("Web Service", show=False):
    ELB("lb") >> EC2("web") >> RDS("userdb")

I should get web_service.png file as per documentation. But I am getting "web_service" file:
digraph "Web Service" {
    graph [fontcolor="#2D3436" fontname="Sans-Serif" fontsize=15 label="Web Service" nodesep=0.60 pad=2.0 rankdir=LR ranksep=0.75 splines=ortho]
    node [fixedsize=true fontcolor="#2D3436" fontname="Sans-Serif" fontsize=13 height=1.4 imagescale=true labelloc=b shape=box style=rounded width=1.4]
    edge [color="#7B8894"]
    "55c1dbf2b98947439179362b1fbdbf0b" [label=lb height=1.9 image="C:\Users\ravim\OneDrive\Desktop\mypython\.venv\Lib\site-packages\resources/aws/network\elastic-load-balancing.png" shape=none]
    db6288db747346ceaec598588b40c452 [label=web height=1.9 image="C:\Users\ravim\OneDrive\Desktop\mypython\.venv\Lib\site-packages\resources/aws/compute\ec2.png" shape=none]
    "55c1dbf2b98947439179362b1fbdbf0b" -> db6288db747346ceaec598588b40c452 [dir=forward fontcolor="#2D3436" fontname="Sans-Serif" fontsize=13]
    b60dbfb720a14392b9969c69bb9653f9 [label=userdb height=1.9 image="C:\Users\ravim\OneDrive\Desktop\mypython\.venv\Lib\site-packages\resources/aws/database\rds.png" shape=none]
    db6288db747346ceaec598588b40c452 -> b60dbfb720a14392b9969c69bb9653f9 [dir=forward fontcolor="#2D3436" fontname="Sans-Serif" fontsize=13]
}


I tried the exact code and it's generating web_service.png for me. What is the version of your diagrams?

diagrams-0.23.4.dist-info and graphviz-0.20.3.dist-info these two libraries i am using.
